# Sending a File in an Embed Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot download an image, change it to a url, and send it in an embed in Discord py. However during the process of changing the file to a url, the directory of the file can never be found. Here is the code I am using to change the file to a url:

```
f = discord.File(f"/Desktop/Bot/Dino_Battles/DinoBattle_{str(ctx.author.id)}_VS_{str(user.id)}.jpg", filename = f'DinoBattle_{str(ctx.author.id)}_VS_{str(user.id)}.jpg')
```

However, I always get an error that the directory cannot be found even when the image is there.
Here is the Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Desktop/Bot/Dino_Battles/DinoBattle_628693454754676768_VS_725411116272058369.jpg
```

And here is the file directory:

```
C:\Users\lbart\Desktop\Bot\Dino_Battles\DinoBattle_628693454754676768_VS_725411116272058369.jpg
```

How is discord not finding the file?
Sorry if this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you upload the file on https://imgur.com/ and then copy the link and use the link instead of a file. It's much easier :>

P.S Remember to use the embed.set_image(url=imgurlink) or embed.set_thumbnail, whichever you want

Comment: oh thats a good idea. There is a way to upload it through python correct?

Comment: What do you mean through python? If you mean like through the files, yes but I wouldn't recommend that unless u were told by your teacher specifically to do whatever it is you're doing right now :>

Comment: Please accept my answer if it works for you :> much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Tam said it is best to upload it to a website. [imgur api docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest). Also this is a good article on how to use it with steps [link](https://rapidapi.com/blog/imgur-api-tutorial/)

Here is an example of how to upload and get the URL using [pyimgur](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur)

```py
import pyimgur

CLIENT_ID = "Your_applications_client_id"
PATH = "A Filepath to an image on your computer"

im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)
uploaded_image = im.upload_image(PATH, title= f'DinoBattle_{str(ctx.author.id)}_VS_{str(user.id)}')
print(uploaded_image.title)
print(uploaded_image.link)
print(uploaded_image.size)
print(uploaded_image.type)
```

After you upload it you can use `uploaded_image.link` as the photo in the embed.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the full path, from

```
f = discord.File(f"/Desktop/Bot/Dino_Battles/DinoBattle_{str(ctx.author.id)}_VS_{str(user.id)}.jpg", filename = f'DinoBattle_{str(ctx.author.id)}_VS_{str(user.id)}.jpg')
```

to

```
f = discord.File(f"c:/Users/lbart/Desktop/Bot/Dino_Battles/DinoBattle_{str(ctx.author.id)}_VS_{str(user.id)}.jpg", filename = f'DinoBattle_{str(ctx.author.id)}_VS_{str(user.id)}.jpg')
```